# mstsc Remote Desktop questions

Tags: vbscript, rdp, mstsc

currently, to improve some inefficiencies on a daily process, I am trying to write a c# Winform app that will combine a mix of user-input with VBscripts that will expedite a previously all user-input process of looking at an excel file and moving files from VSS to certain folders of certain servers.

I was hoping to get some questions answered, pointed in the right way:

Using command line or other workaround instead of manually,

1) Is it possible to log into a 2003 remote desktop with a Smartcard/pin?

2) Is it possible to run a file/start a process on the remote desktop from a command on your machine?

Thanks for the help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only experience with the second question. 
You can do this with remote scripting or with utilities like SysInternals PsExec http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx
here a vbscript that remotely starts a ipconfig command and redirects it to a textfile
Note that you can't start interactive processes like this, they would start but not show up

```
Dim sComputer   'computer name
Dim sCmdLine    'command line of the process
Dim sCurDir   'working directory of the process
Dim oProcess    'object representing the Win32_Process class
Dim oMethod   'object representing the Create method
sComputer = "." 'this is the local computer, use a pcname or ip-adress to do it remote
sCmdLine = "cmd /c ipconfig.exe > c:\ipconfig.txt"
Set oProcess    = GetObject("winmgmts://" & sComputer & "/root/cimv2:Win32_Process")
Set oMethod     = oProcess.Methods_("Create")
Set oInPar    = oMethod.inParameters.SpawnInstance_()
oInPar.CommandLine  = sCmdLine
oInPar.CurrentDirectory = sCurDir
Set oOutPar     = oProcess.ExecMethod_("Create", oInPar)
If oOutPar.ReturnValue  = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Create process method completed successfully"
  WScript.Echo "New Process ID is " & oOutPar.ProcessId
Else
  WScript.Echo "Create process method failed"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Was looking at this but wasn't sure if company would approve it. Will try soon. Anything I should know about it's licensing?

Comment: psexec is freeware as far as i know, but m$ took it over so check to be sure if important